# XmlHttprequest : How do not let the server wait for the next request

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I want to ask the server to get the data.
The data comes in normally, but it takes a lot of time.

What I want to do is send `xmlhttpRequest.send (null)` from Client side, send response data fastly from server side.

i checked the server side log to solve time-consuming problem, and found that: 
Even after receiving `xmlhttpRequest.send (null)` it waits for the next request and eventually times out.

i wonder if this is a server-side problem or a client-side problem using xmlhttprequest.

**Client-side code**

```
function HomeLoad() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/HomeLoad.asp', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4){
            if(xhr.status == 200){
                //home_Arr = xhr.responseText.split('&');
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send(null);
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
  HomeLoad();
});
```

Comment: server side most likely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronous XHR requests often cause hangs on the web. But developers typically don't notice the problem because the hang only manifests with poor network conditions or when the remote server is slow to respond. Synchronous XHR is now in deprecation state. The recommendation is that developers move away from the synchronous API and use synchronous requests.

For more information refer below URL:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', '/bar/foo.txt', false);  // `false` makes the request synchronous
request.send(null);

if (request.status === 200) {
  console.log(request.responseText);
}
```

For Asynchronous Request:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/bar/foo.txt", true);
xhr.onload = function (e) {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
    } else {
      console.error(xhr.statusText);
    }
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function (e) {
  console.error(xhr.statusText);
};
xhr.send(null);
```

Line 2 specifies true for its third parameter to indicate that the request should be handled asynchronously.